# How to use year counter google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have following data in a google sheet

[image: current situation]

i need to add a year counter to the column d as follows using google apps script

[image: needed]

Comment: I apologize for the hurry. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your expected result. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for it?

Comment: No worries i apologize for disturbance, i’d like to count the years between each variant and leave the last one as zero or null for being the current year

Comment: The employee x started working at the vacancy A at certain date 1/1/2012 then he moved to vacancy B at 1/1/2013 then to vacancy C at 1/1/2016 so he passed 1 year at vacancy A and 3 years at vacancy B and so on

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the logic for obtaining your expected result. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

> ***NOTE**: This script is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

Based on your description, it seems you want to subtract the subsequent years per cell in column D, where the years are separated by `new lines (\n)`. The result of the subtraction should be displayed adjacent to the corresponding column A references, also separated by new lines.

To tackle this in Google Apps Script, you can split the column D values by the new line character, subtract the subsequent years, and then join the results with new lines. Here's an example script as a custom Google Sheet function:

### Sample Script *[updated]*

```
function yearsCount(range) {
  var letters = [];
  var years = [];
  range.forEach(x => (letters.push(x[0].split(/\r?\n/)), years.push(x[1].split(/\r?\n/)))); //Loop & push the letters & years

  return years.map(x => x.map((y, i, arr) => { //Iterate through the years
    try {
      var yearData = (parseInt(arr[i + 1].match(/\d{4}/)[0]) - parseInt(y.match(/\d{4}/)[0]));
      return letters[0][i] + ' ' + (yearData > 1 ? yearData + ' years' : yearData + ' year');//Subtract the current year to the next year
    } catch {
      var yearData2 = new Date().getUTCFullYear() - parseInt(y.match(/\d{4}/)[0]); //Subract the last year to the current year
      return letters[0][i] + ' ' + (yearData2 > 1 ? yearData2 + ' years' : yearData2 + ' year');
    }
  })).map(x => [x.join('\n')]); // restructure the year array and join them with new line to be returned back to sheet
}
```

### Demo

[image]

### References

- [map()](https://spreadsheet.dev/array-method-map-in-apps-script)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: firstly thank you, can we fix the last year to be subtracted from 2023? instead of the word current or null, i mean to get the result of subtraction of 2023 and the value of the year from  the last entry ?

Comment: @user20795119 You're welcome. I have updated my answer made the last year entry to be subtracted to the current year (2023)